# real device android emulator not visualized on adb

Tags: android, emulation

I installed a driver for my Galaxy Tab 2.0 on to my PC in order to use it as an emulator, but ADB Manager doesn't display it.

I've enabled USB debugging on the device and after connecting it to my PC.

Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: You installed **USB Driver** but have you installed **Android ADB Interface Driver**?

Comment: type `adb devices` in console to check if is detected.

Comment: @MD i' ve checked by cmd on my adb's folder and i ' ve installed the android adb interface driver.